# Objective C - View behind UINavigationController & TabBarController

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on an app that uses UINavigationController & TabBarController.
When I look in the NIB file, I see that the "view" for a section of the TabBarController is added below the UINavigationController & above the Tab itself.

Picture attached:
[image]

How can I add that view behind the UINavigationController & behind TabBarController?
I'm trying to make it go full screen. I'm able to hide the UINavigationController & TabBarController but the size of the view just stays the same.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIViewController`s `wantsFullscreen` property.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL wantsFullScreenLayout;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I actually also have to do "self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;" to get the view behind the UINavigationController & status bar. This is getting super close, but I can't seem to get the "view" to also expand behind the TabBarController. Any suggestions? Thanks, Tee

Comment: Sure, use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` (but it has to be a secondary view controller for this). AFAIK you won't be able to hide the tab-controller (in a nice way) when it's already displayed.